# Merge array text per user

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

How to merge correctly to get from this array:

```
x = [[0,"TEXT1",1,2],[0,"TEXT2",3,4],[0,"TEXT3",6,7],[1,"TEXT4",10,12],[1,"TEXT5",13,14],[1,"TEXT6",16,17],[0,"TEXT7",18,19]]

x[0][0] = User number
x[0][1] = Word
x[0][2] = Time FROM
x[0][3] = Time To
```

What I need is to get something this:

```
User 0: TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3 From 1 to 7
User 1: TEXT4 TEXT5 TEXT6 From 10 to 17
User 0: TEXT7 From 18 to 19
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

- As my idea of creating a lot of subarrays and then combining all together looks like bad coding...

Extra Explanation:

Inside the array we can see these element - `[0,"TEXT1",1,2]`

- 0 = user ID
- TEXT1 = the word user 0 said
- 1 = start saying it at second 1
- 2 finished saying at second 2

Then after a while we can see - `[1,"TEXT4",10,12]`

- This is the same as before but here we can see that user (with ID 1) start talking

Comment: If this is an IQ test I'm failing. Where's the pattern behind your desired output?

Comment: If you checking array, first array inside is a word, (the first element is the user number, then text, then at what second he said it, and in which second he finished saying it...).. Then you can see user number changed to 1.. this mean it is second user start talking

Comment: Oh I got it now, but the explanation could be better :)

Comment: Maybe [edit] your post to explain a bit better?

Comment: Doing it with bad coding is better than not doing it at all

Comment: Have explained it in more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

For each group (which is a sequence of a user's elements), we take all the words, the minimum "from" and the maximum "to".

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

x = [[0,"TEXT1",1,2],[0,"TEXT2",3,4],[0,"TEXT3",6,7],[1,"TEXT4",10,12],[1,"TEXT5",13,14],[1,"TEXT6",16,17],[0,"TEXT7",18,19]]

result = []
for k,g in groupby(x, key=itemgetter(0)):
    ks, words, froms, tos = zip(*g)
    result.append([k, words, min(froms), max(tos)])

print(result)
```

It gives the output in a structures way, printing it to exactly match your output should be very easy from there.

Comment: Can someone help with making this a one-line with list comprehension? I'm having trouble with unpacking the `zip` to multiple vars inside a list comp >_<